# Push_back variadic function parameters into a vector?

Tags: c++, debugging, variadic-functions, variadic

I am trying to push_back the parameters of a variadic function as shown below, but the compiler says there is a type mismatch (due to the parameters being a general type while the vector is int). What should I do to make the parameters compatible?

```
vector<int> x;
template<typename... Rest>
void foo(Rest... rest) {
    x.push_back(rest...);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++14 and before:

```
void foo(Rest... rest) {
    int a[] = {0, (x.push_back(rest), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(a);  // unused
}
```

In C++17:

```
void foo(Rest... rest) {
    (x.push_back(rest), ...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the purpose of a[] though?

Comment: are you sure those push_backs has to be evaluated left to right? otherwise you might get items in confusing order.

Comment: @sp2danny: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a base case:

```
void push_all(vector<int>&) {}
```

Continue with 'gradual unpacking'

```
template<typename... Rest>
void push_all(vector<int>& vec, int val, Rest... rest)
{
    vec.push_back(val);
    push_all(vec, rest...);
}
```

Not as compact, but a little easier to grok.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer this version as it's faster and works on C++11 too.

```cpp
template<typename... Rest>
void foo(Rest... rest) {
    x.insert(x.end(), { static_cast<decltype(x)::value_type>(rest)...});
}
```

But if you for some reason need to use `push_back()` then at least call `reserve()` to make it faster.

```cpp
template<typename... Rest>
void foo(Rest... rest) {
    x.reserve(sizeof...(Rest));
    (x.push_back(rest), ...);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31436106)

Comment: @kamshi "This does not provide an answer to the question." Please explain...

Comment: op asked about how to make the parameters `Rest...` "compatible". What he probably means is how to store arbitrary types in a vector, for example using std::any. Your solution doesn't solve this problem, you only focused on performance (see here, it does not compile for non-integer types: https://godbolt.org/z/9dGPbnoGv), which is why I flagged your post as not answering the question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to fix that. Thank you for noticing my mistake though.